# React "magically" updates two states instead of one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, state

I have two states defined like so:

```
  const [productProperties, setProductProperties] = useState<
    PropertyGroup[] | null
  >(null);
  const [originalProductProperties, setOriginalProductProperties] = useState<
    PropertyGroup[] | null
  >(null);
```

The first one is supposed to be updated through user input and the second one is used later for a comparison so that only the `PropertyGroup`'s that have changed values will be submitted via API to be updated.

I have done this a thousand times before, but for some reason when I change the `name` value for a `PropertyGroup` and update the state for 'productProperties' like so:

```
  (e, itemId) => {
    const update = [...productProperties];
    const i = update.findIndex((group) => group.id === itemId);
    if (i !== -1) {
      update[i].name = {
        ...update[i].name,
        [selectedLocale]: e.currentTarget.value,
      };
      setProductProperties([...update]);
    }
  }
```

The state of `originalProductProperties` also updates. Why? `setOriginalProductProperties` is never called here, I am also not mutating any state directly and I use the spread operator to be sure to create new references. I am lost.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example? Side note: You could simplify your state update logic by using the `map()` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface: It sounds like the two arrays are sharing the same objects. That's fine provided you handle updates correctly.

Although you're copying the *array*, you're modifying the object in the array directly. That's breaking the main rule of state: [Do Not Modify State Directly](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Instead, make a copy of the object as well:

```
(e, itemId) => {
    const update = [...productProperties];
    const i = update.findIndex((group) => group.id === itemId);
    if (i !== -1) {
        update[i] = { // *** Note making a new object
            ...update[i],
            [selectedLocale]: e.currentTarget.value,
        };;
        setProductProperties(update); // (No need to *re*copy the array here, you've already done it at the top of the function)
    }
}
```

Or, since you have that `i !== -1` check there, we could copy the array later so we don't copy it if we don't find the group matching `itemId`:

```
(e, itemId) => {
    const i = productProperties.findIndex((group) => group.id === itemId);
    if (i !== -1) {
        const update = [...productProperties];
        update[i] = { // *** Note making a new object
            ...update[i],
            [selectedLocale]: e.currentTarget.value,
        };;
        setProductProperties(update);
    }
}
```

---

FWIW, in cases where you *know* there will be a match, `map` is good for this (but probably not in this case, since you seem to indicate the group may not be there):

```
(e, itemId) => {
    const update = productProperties.map((group) => {
        if (group.id === itemId) {
            // It's the one we want, create the replacement
            group = {
                ...group,
                [selectedLocale]: e.currentTarget.value,
            };
        }
        return group;
    });
    setProductProperties(update);
}
```

Or sometimes you see it written with a conditional operator:

```
(e, itemId) => {
    const update = productProperties.map((group) =>
        group.id === itemId
            ? { // It's the one we want, create a replacement
                ...group,
                [selectedLocale]: e.currentTarget.value,
            }
            : group
    );
    setProductProperties(update);
}
```

Comment: Wow, simply missed that I didn't use the spread opeartor for the object itself. Thought I was going insane, thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @Pixell - No worries!! <pedantry>`...` isn't an operator, it's primary syntax. Operators can't do what rest and spread do. :-D </pedantry>

Comment: `<pedantry>` should officially be an html tag...

Comment: @Yousaf - LOL!! Definitely has semantic meaning...